# Bootstrap CSS nested style class not applying

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Need some help with CSS styling CSS experts!
Using bootstrap in which 
they have the following defined in bootstrap.css:

```
.table > tbody > tr.active > td{ 
   background-color:#f5f5f5;}
```

I'm trying to highlight a row in a table when a user clicks it- easy enough,

my html structure follows exactly and I have the active class being inserted to the html when I click the row but it is just not highlighting and the style does not get applied...

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div ng-class=".....">
<div id="firstTable" class="group-table-split-body">
<table class="table-bordered table-condensed table-hover col-md-12">
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items"
        ng-mouseenter="..."
        ng-mouseleave="..."
        ng-click="onRowClick(item)">
       <td class="col-md-12">{{item.name}}.....
       </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   .......................
```

however, if I try it with just a random test style class it works, like:

```
.anything
 {background-color:#f5f5f5;}
```

so if I try .anything, it highlights....

I'm using Firefox...any ideas??

Comment: Do you have any other CSS defined for `td`?

Comment: Hmm not one for .table > tbody > tr.active > td that is the only one for .table > tbody > tr.active > td

Comment: some more html for better overview regarding .table?

Comment: not sure it'll help but added some

Comment: missed class "table" in <table class="table-bordered table-condensed table-hover col-md-12">...i'm a dumbasss...thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten class table from your table :)

Comment: Thanks Havunen for the help!

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is:
First make sure your own css file is loaded AFTER bootstrap.min.css
(this way your rules has higher priority)
After that you can easily override that bootstrap style by copying the exact same rule and changing its properties. 
for example in your css add:

```
.table > tbody > tr.active > td{ 
   background-color:red;}
```

and you will see difference. Another way to do this is by creating more specific rule that will override the bootstrap rule for example, I assume your base element here with class "table" is actually table so you could do this:

```
table.table > tbody > tr.active > td{ 
   background-color:blue;}
```

Easiest and fastest solution to this problem is by overriding the property with important rule. But this is by far the worst solution and you should try to avoid important as long as possible (it will create problems later on). 
However if nothing seems to work you can do it like this:

```
.active {
   background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the list of solutions, before I overwrite anything I wanted know why the style is not loading from bootstrap.css in the first place...

Comment: Ahaa, I think i misunderstood your question. So you want to use the default color that SHOULD come from bootstrap but is not applied?

Comment: Yes I would like to do that if possible...it's not getting applied for some reason. I do have a couple of my own css files that loads after, but none overwrites .table > tbody > tr.active > td

Comment: Well the problem is in your other css files for sure. You can use firebug computed tab to look where the specific rule is coming from. But if I add active class to basic example table that is shown here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables
the highlight color gets applied.

Comment: Hmm..i removed all my own css files except bootstrap.css and it still does not work haha

Comment: also tried just setting <tr class="active"> and took out everything else...no luck...wat the heck...

Comment: Do you have class "table" in your table? ;)

I created jsfiddle where it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/Km3Br/

Comment: hey, thanks for the fiddle! so i missed table in <table class="table-bordered table-condensed table-hover col-md-12"> haha!! i'm a dumbass...so adding table fixed it! Thanks for all your help <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover col-md-12">

Answer (score 0):

```
.table > tbody > tr.active > td{ 
   background-color:#f5f5f5;}
```

where is the class `"table"` ?

make it this

```
table > tbody > tr.active > td{ 
   background-color:#f5f5f5;}
```

Comment: the table is defined in the bootstrap.css a little bit above the .table > tbody > tr.active > td  .table should work